# inotifywait doesn't monitor Windows users saving to Samba share on Linux

Tags: linux, windows, inotify, samba4

I have `inotifywait`(version 3.14) on Linux to monitor a folder that is shared with Samba Version 4.3.9-Ubuntu.

It works if I copy a file from Linux machine to samba share(that is on different machine, under Linux as well).

But if I copy a file from Windows machine `inotify` won't detect anything.
Spaces or no spaces, recursive or not result is the same.

```
printDir="/media/smb_share/temp/monitor"
inotifywait -m -r -e modify -e create "$printDir" |  while read line
do
    echo "$line"
done
```

Does anyone have any ideas of how to solve it?

Comment: If you remove the `while` loop do you get any timely output from `inotifywait`?

Comment: It should work. I have something like that running and i don't see any obvious mistakes in your setup. Please double check for "stupid" mistakes like using the wrong directory or server ;)

Comment: Without the loop it still doesn't catch anything. Yes, i tripled check the directory if i copy from Linux it catches an event but not from Windows.

Comment: If you remove the `-e modify -e create` filters what events do you get?

Comment: Nothing, no events if copy from Windows. Copying from Linux i get all kinds of different events including the ones i am looking for.

Comment: Your directory is `/media/smb_share/...` this _is_ a local filesystem? And it matches exactly the path you've defined for the share in your local `smb.conf`? `inotifywait` can only see events on local filesystems.

Comment: Yes it is. Script runs on a server that shares this directory through Samba to Linux and Windows clients. Only Linux clients were happy about it though.

Comment: Very strange. Works for me from Windows to a Samba share on my server's local filesystem.

Comment: Incidentally, if that workaround script is your own (reluctant) answer, please move it out of the question and into an answer. You can then accept that answer (if you get nothing better).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, its an ugly workaround but for my case it should work in ~90% of cases.

```
temPrint=/dev/shm/print
fcheck_1=$temPrint/fcheck_1
fcheck_new=$temPrint/fcheck_new
fcheck_old=$temPrint/fcheck_old
fcheck_preprint=$temPrint/fcheck_preprint
fcheck_print=$temPrint/fcheck_print
printDir="/media/smb_share/temp/monitor"

test -d $temPrint || mkdir $temPrint

while [ true ]; do
  test -e $fcheck_new && rm $fcheck_new
  test -e $fcheck_old || touch $fcheck_old
  test -e $fcheck_print && rm $fcheck_print

  ls -l "$printDir"/*.pdf > $fcheck_1
  while read line
  do
    echo "${line#*"/"}" | sed "s#^#/#" >> $fcheck_new
  done < $fcheck_1

  rt=$(diff $fcheck_new $fcheck_old | grep "<")
  if [ "$rt" ]; then
    echo "$rt" > $fcheck_preprint
    while read line
    do
      echo "${line#*"/"}" | sed "s#^#/#" >> $fcheck_print
    done < $fcheck_preprint

    while read line
    do
      echo "$line"
    done < $fcheck_print

    cp $fcheck_new $fcheck_old
  fi
  sleep 20
done
```

Answer (score 0):

You should give [fileschanged](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/en/man1/fileschanged.1.html) a chance

I just tested it with mounted CIFS drives from Windows. It worked like a charme with almost no latency or server load.

- To install:

  ```
  sudo apt-get install fileschanged
  ```
- To monitor e.g. your home folder for any new or changed files

  ```
  fileschanged -s created,changed -t1 $PWD
  ```
- The output will look like this:

  ```
  /mnt/winshare/DevRep/VMTest/trigger_test1 folder/test3
  /mnt/winshare/DevRep/VMTest/trigger_test1 folder/test3
  /mnt/winshare/DevRep/VMTest/trigger_test1 folder/test4
  ```

As you can see, it works with spaces inside paths as well.